# What is the directory that my camera files are under?

Tags: terminal, finder, usb, filesystem, camera

I've been trying to change the permission on my external camera (Cannon brand) to read and write, but have had trouble locating the device's directory. It uses USB 3.0, and it shows up in system information, but I can't find it in the finder or terminal.

Comment: Not sure it shows up at all (macOS is not Linux). Which problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: What is the name of the app you are using to view the camera’s video feed and, presumably, save the images/videos that you’re having trouble granting permission to?